# Outgoing connection proxy for http ingoing traffic

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, proxy

I've got two applications, a client and a rest server on two different servers.
The server is in the DMZ, and the client is on a hosted server.
My entreprise IT department wants to have only ontgoing connexions to the hosted server so that the firewall only sees outgoing connections.
They sugsets to have the following architecture :

hosted                   dmz
Client <---------------> Server
Proxy server             Proxy client

1) Proxy server opens a tcp socket
2) Proxy client connects to this tcp socket permanently
3) http requests can be forwarded from client app to rest server app through the tcp connection

Do you know any software that implements such an active proxy mechanism ? (eg apache, nginx...)
Is it more secure that just opening port 80 for the web hosted machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know any software that implements such an active proxy mechanism ?

There are a variety of solutions: from netcat (nc) to socks5. I suggest you to start with netcat, since it is much easier to understand and configure.

> Is it more secure that just opening port 80 for the web hosted machine ?

Yes, it is more secure that just forwarding port 80 to DMZ, since you are punching a hole in firewall just for the specific flow.

On the other hand, adding an access list on top of 80 port forwarding should make it even, but there might be other issues, like corporate politics, hardware limitations etc...

Comment: Can you provide an example ? Is it transparent for the application ?

Comment: @Kiruahxh example of netcat?

Comment: Yes, a netcat example that could make the job